# Identifying appimage program names for devilspie

Tags: appimage, devilspie

I am trying to figure out how to identify a name for my appimage for use with my devilspie startup setup

I have simply used program names to setup devilspie so I must be missing something as the appimage isn't registering by its setup.

Below I have the simple setup on devilspie that I used for Thunderbird, Discord etc. I just can't pin down the appimage name from anywhere to define it.

```
(if
(is (application_name) "Chatterino")
(begin
(set_workspace 4)
)
)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To see information about the windows, including the application that owns it, you can use `xlsclients`. More information, including window class and icon, is provided by `xclients -l`. Much more info is provided by `xprop`. When you run that command, you must click the window on which you want information.